# Angular material radio button unchecked on opening angular modal pop up

Tags: angular, angular-material

We are using angular material mat radio button and it is selected.  This radio button gets unchecked on opening angular modal pop up with another set of angular material radio button.

````
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" formControlName="selectedToRole" [name]="selectedRole"  >
                                <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let item of rolesForTransferToRadio"  [value]="item.role" (change)="displayBasedOnSelectedRole(item.role)">
                                    <span class="labelFontsValue col-md-3">{{item.roleCode}}&nbsp;</span>
                                </mat-radio-button>
                            </mat-radio-group>

```Typescript
this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(loadPlantLocationsContent);
````

Comment: Can you add some code what you done?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RuudVerhoef my question is why the radio button is unchecked on opening angular modal pop up?

Comment: @Tushar Added the code which gets unchecked on opening a modal pop up

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for radio button selected by default

Can you try adding the following CSS class to radio button

```
mat-radio-checked
```